# What GNU/Linux magazines, e-zines are available?

Tags: documentation

What GNU/Linux specific magazines, e-zines (free and paid) are there ?

Answer (score 6):

## [Full Circle Magazine](http://fullcirclemagazine.org/)

> Full Circle is a free, independent,
> monthly magazine dedicated to the
> Ubuntu family of Linux operating
> systems. Each month, it contains
> helpful how-to articles and reader
> submitted stories.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ubuntu User](http://www.ubuntu-user.com/)

> Ubuntu User is a print magazine for
> the Ubuntu Community. In addition to
> reviews, interviews, community news,
> HowTo articles, troubleshooting tips,
> and in-depth technical articles,
> Ubuntu User includes a helpful
> Discovery Guide for readers who are
> new to the world of Ubuntu. A free DVD
> included with each issue of Ubuntu
> User provides an easy way for users to
> upgrade to the latest version. New
> users can boot from the DVD drive
> without disturbing the existing
> installation.

Answer (score 4):

**[Linux Format](http://www.linuxformat.com/)**

UK based Linux Magazine, from their 'About' page:

Each month, Linux Format includes:

```
All the latest news and analysis from the Linux scene
In-depth reviews of new software and book releases
Extensive features on apps, trends and the community
Revealing interviews with key Linux players
Detailed tutorials - from basics to programming
```

You also get a 4GB cover DVD featuring the best new distros (eg Mandriva, SUSE and Ubuntu) along with stacks of software - desktop apps, development tools and games, to keep you up-to-date. Plus, the disc includes extra guides and tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

[**Linux Magazine**](http://www.linux-magazine.com/)

> Linux Magazine delivers insightful technical articles on a range of topics related to IT technology, including:
>
> - Comprehensive coverage of technical subjects. Recent cover stories have explored topics such as hotplugging, rootkits, virtualization, and cryptography.
> - Thorough reviews of new products. Many reviews are written by the experienced engineers within Linux New Media’s advanced test lab.
> - Practical advice on tools and strategies for system administrators.
>   Tips on programming in the Linux environment.
>   Discussions of advanced desktop techniques.

Comment: It's worth noting that Linux Magazine just went completely digital :(

Answer (score 2):

**[Linux Weekly News](https://lwn.net)**

> LWN.net aims to be the premier news and information source for the free software community. We provide comprehensive coverage of development, legal, commercial, and security issues. The LWN.net Weekly Edition is our weekly summary of what has happened in the free software world; our front page offers up-to-the-minute coverage.

Only the current edition [costs money](https://lwn.net/subscribe/Info), while the older ones are available for free.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a other e-zine for free.
I don't now if anyone has notice it.
It's the PClos magazine and you'l find it on http://pclosmag.com/.
Enjoy!!